# Paypal | Website Payment Standard | Address Override

Tags: paypal

I have set up a website with integration with paypal's Payment Standard. This includes address_override=1 to send to paypal a fixed the delivery address.

A "helpful" feature of paypal is that it pre-populates the uploaded address into the billing address fields for an unregistered user.

If the user then fills in their credit card details their card will obviously be declined as the billing address must match their card. All works fine if the user realises the error and replaces my uploaded address with their real billing address, but the client im working for is nervous that users will not realise to do this... I have to agree somewhat.

Does anyone know of a solution to this? some variable I'm missing in the standard variables docu's from Paypal which says:

> "thiis is an address override, but only uise it for delivery adress, never billing address"

Comment: Link to the docu from Paypal?

Answer (score 0):

a year too late for a reply but I had the same problem.

I cannot separate the billing and shipping address. In my case, users can buy items as gift so the billing and shipping address will be different...and just today, I recently found out [PayPal has no way to separate both](https://www.x.com/message/177152). Oh boy.

Answer (score -1):

In the script that commnunicates with PayPal, there will be an `"address_override" => "1"`. Simply, change this to `"address_override" => "0"`.

Comment: you miss the point, I *want* to override the address, I just want(ed) it to be delivery address only, not billing address. But well done for answering an 8 month old question ;)